# How do I cast a "FrameworkElement" to a "Line Shape" in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm trying to iterate through a series of "Line Shapes" on a "Canvas" using "foreach".
In the body of the "foreach" I want to make changes to the "X1","Y1","X2","Y2" coordinates of each "Line".

I have created a simple example below.
The following small snippet of XAML and C# code, creates 3 lines on a canvas.

```
<Window x:Class="TestCase.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Canvas Height="500" Width="500" Name="My_Canvas">
       <Line StrokeThickness="10" Stroke="Black" X1="100" Y1="100" X2="200" Y2="100"
             Tag="Line #1"/>
       <Line StrokeThickness="10" Stroke="Black" X1="100" Y1="200" X2="200" Y2="200"
             Tag="Line #2"/>
       <Line StrokeThickness="10" Stroke="Black" X1="100" Y1="300" X2="200" Y2="300"
             Tag="Line #3"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestCase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (FrameworkElement Hold_Element in My_Canvas.Children)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Tag = " + Hold_Element.Tag);

                //(Line)Hold_Element.X1 = (Line)Hold_Element.X1 + 90;           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The C# code iterates through the lines, and correctly displays the "Tag" of each "Line" in the Message box.

The line that is commented out is the code I want to apply.

I want to move the X1 coordinate of each "Line" by 90 units to the right.
How do I make this commented out line valid?
I can't get the casting correct...
Somehow I must cast the "FrameworkElement" to a "Line Shape" and set the "X1" coordinate on the "Line Shape".

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have it right -- just have to put extra parentheses around the cast:

```
((Line)Hold_Element).X1 = ((Line)Hold_Element).X1 + 90;
```

Alternatively, note that you could specify the type in the `foreach` statement, using the `OfType` Linq extension method:

```
foreach (Line Hold_Element in My_Canvas.Children)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Tag = " + Hold_Element.Tag.OfType<Line>());
    Hold_Element.X1 = Hold_Element.X1 + 90;           
}
```

The second approach is preferable, as it will only return elements of the correct type (thus you don't risk a runtime "invalid cast" exception).

Comment: Thanks McGarnagle.    I went with  ((Line)Hold_Element).X1 = ((Line)Hold_Element).X1 + 90;   Both methods work like a champ, but I needed to go with the longer casting method.

Answer (score 1):

**Typecasting is not proper**. Wrap object in parenthesis to access it's property (X1 in your case).

Replace

```
(Line)Hold_Element.X1 = (Line)Hold_Element.X1 + 90;
```

to

```
((Line)Hold_Element).X1 = ((Line)Hold_Element).X1 + 90;
```

Comment: Yep...((Line)Hold_Element).X1 = ((Line)Hold_Element).X1 + 90;...is just what I needed.